# Google Structured Data Testing Tool doesn't recognize 'organizer' as a property of 'schema.org/Event'

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to mark up an Event with schema.org Microdata, but when I test with [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) I get told:

> Error: Page contains property "organizer" which is not part of the schema.

But `organizer` is part of the schema: http://schema.org/organizer

Here's a simple example of the markup:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <p><span itemprop="name">My Birthday</span> 
        on <span itemprop="startDate">17 September 2014</span></p>
    <div itemprop="organizer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <p>Organized by <span itemprop="name">ME</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it a Google error? Am I making a stupid mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Discovered that 'organizer' is a feature of schema.org 1.7 from circa Jul 2014 : http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2014Jul/0012.html

It seems Google isn't keeping up...